# React TS universal hack for inputs with useState doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've seen typescript solution with universal handle change function, but in my case it works bad. Need help to understand why this happens.

When I add new product - it adds correctly, but when I try to clear Input manually - first rerender it also changes already added content.

Algorithm to see this mistake: fill inputs, add submit and remove one letter from title input - you'll see that it affects already added title in another state, but only on first rerender

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-dream-do7bqh?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Please try to change the `setProduct` (in `handleChange` method) like so: `setProduct(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));`. Please share feedback if it helped or creates any other issues.

Comment: Yes, your solution works perfectly well. Add it as an answer please. And also why my approach doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code-sample may be a solution to achieve the desired objective:

In the `handleChange` method:

```
setProduct(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
```

**Explanation**

- The `prev` value of `product` is taken as-is
- Then, using the `...` spread-operator all of `prev`'s props are spread
- This is now followed with `[name]` which is a new prop being added with `value` as the corresponding value
- Any existing prop will be replaced.

Suppose `name` variable has the value `'title'` and `value` is `'Testing 123'`, then the `product` object becomes:

```
product = {
  id: previousValueOfId,
  price: previousValueOfPrice,
  title: 'Testing 123'
}
```

Here, `previousValueOfId` and `previousValueOfPrice` are supposed to be the values.

**Why OP's code did not get the desired result**

The code is:

```
setProduct((prev) => {
  (prev as any)[name] = value;
  const newValue = { ...prev };
  return newValue;
});
```

- This takes the `prev` product, and changes it's `[name]` prop.
- When `prev` is changed, it may impact UI elements which are rendered using `product`.

(NOTE: I am still very new to ReactJS & if this is incorrect kindly update appropriately).